# module prestashop view details of orders

Tags: javascript, ajax, prestashop

salam

i want to view details of orders like the one in history orders

i user the history.js but i dont get the page that view details orders

here is some code

```
{foreach from=$orders item=order name=myLoop}
    {if $order.id_order_state==5}
        {if isset($order.invoice) && $order.invoice && isset($order.virtual) && $order.virtual}
        {/if}
        -|-
        {$order.id_order}
        {Order::getUniqReferenceOf($order.id_order)}
        -|-
        {$order.date_add|date_format:'Y-m-d H:i:s'}

        -|-
            {foreach from=$histories item=history name=hLoop}
                {if $history[0].id_order==$order.id_order}
                    {$history[0].date_add}
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        -|-

        {$order.payment|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
        -|-
        {if isset($order.order_state)}{$order.order_state|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
        {/if}

        <br>
            <a class="color-myaccount" href="javascript:showOrder(1, {$order.id_order|intval}, '{$base_dir}?fc=module&module={$module_name}&controller=products');">{l s='details'}</a>


    {/if}

{/foreach}
```

this code view order and details get details order

but i dont get the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function it's static:

```
Order::getOrdersWithInformations()
```

You can get from it, date add + id_customer + total_paid + stats and more..

Answer (score 0):

What is the PS version ?

For 1.5 : Look at the class "OrderDetailControllerCore" (controllers/front/) & the order-detail.tpl (themes/your_template/)

Comment: thnks, yes i viewed this files, but i didn't get the details in the orders pages!!!!